# Access outside variable from anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I asked this earlier, got linked to [**This Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) which didn't really help me what so ever.

I have got a list of instances of a class, these classes store reference to an DOM element, and a method, and an INT.

I need to go through each of these class instances and assign the method to the click event of the elements.

```
for(var i = 0, l=children.length; i<l; i++) {
      var child = children[i];
      if(child.nodeType === 1 && child.tagName === "LI") {
        listItems[x] = new subMenu(child);
        child.addEventListener('click', function(x) {
          listItems[x].toggle(); <!------- x is always 7, it should be 0-6
        }, false);
        x++;
      }
    }
```

Below is the class:

```
class subMenu {
      constructor(obj) {
        this.elm = obj;
        this.state = 0;
      }

      toggle() {
        if (this.state === 0) {
          addClass(this.elm, 'toggled');
          this.state = 1;
        } else {
          removeClass(this.elm, 'toggled');
          this.state = 0;  
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is an image of the `listItems`:
[image]

**Edit:**
If I make the changes I believe to be correct from the linked post, I get this:

```
var menuParent = document.getElementById('megamenu');
    var children = menuParent.childNodes;
    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 0, l=children.length; i<l; i++) {
      var child = children[i];
      if(child.nodeType === 1 && child.tagName === "LI") {
        listItems[x] = new subMenu(child);
        child.addEventListener('click', bindToggle(x), false);
        x++;
      }
    }
    function bindToggle(i) {
      return listItems[i].toggle();
    }
  }, false);
```

However the `toggle()` method is simply running once on assignment and then not running again when I click the element.

**Edit 2**
Sorry i did actually do it correct the first time, just got the code wrong above. So i have amended my code to return a function to the EventHandler.

```
var menuParent = document.getElementById('megamenu');
    var children = menuParent.childNodes;
    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 0, l=children.length; i<l; i++) {
      var child = children[i];
      if(child.nodeType === 1 && child.tagName === "LI") {
        listItems[x] = new subMenu(child);
        child.addEventListener('click', bindToggle(x), false);
        x++;
      }
    }
    function bindToggle(x) {
      return function() { console.log("Value: " + x); }; // listItems[x].toggle();
    }
```

However the `console.log` is simply outputting

> Value: 2

If I add a `console.log(x)` the line above the EventHandler` then it displays 0-6 like it should, so the value im passing over to the function shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: _"got linked to a thread which didn't really help me what so ever."_ Perhaps mention which one, and why it didn't help, so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: Sorry, I was linked to this thread but I couldn't associate the code shown there with my individual issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: It has just been marked as a duplicate by Quentin again, that clearly isn't helping me and im struggling to apply it to my code...

Comment: The issue i'm having is if I create an entire function just to assign the toggle() method to the click event, then the function is being executed on assignment, and then executing when I click the element like it should.

Comment: Bottom line, you have a function inside a loop and use a variable within the function that's being modified by the loop.  The linked question clearly talks through the issue and what to do about it - take a step back and have a fresh look at it.

Comment: "The issue i'm having is if I create an entire function just to assign the toggle() method to the click event, then the function is being executed on assignment, and then executing when I click the element like it should" — That doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Try creating an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you are having implementing the solutions you were given instead of ignoring those solutions and just repeating the original question.

Comment: The duplicate question has 14 answers that have a score of 10 or more. Just shrugging and saying you don't understand any of them doesn't give anyone much to go on if they want to help you understand.

Comment: @Quentin updated my post

Answer (score 2):

This is the code from the accepted answer on the referenced question:

> ```
> function createfunc(i) {
>     return function() { console.log("My value: " + i); };
> }
> ```

It returns a function. (The return value is passed to `addEventListener`).

This is your equivalent code:

> ```
> function bindToggle(i) {
>   return listItems[i].toggle();
> }
> ```

It just *does stuff* and then returns nothing (`undefined`).

Then this code:

> ```
> child.addEventListener('click', bindToggle(x), false);
> ```

Trying to bind `undefined` as the event handler.

You have to pass a function to `addEventListener`